# Can't find artifact in SVN repository

Tags: java, xml, svn, maven

I want to set my project to dependency with another project that i have deploy to SVN repository already but the problem occur it said like this:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ForSentProject 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://Mac-PC/svn/Project/com/mycompany/TempT/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/TempT-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.mycompany:TempT:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: https://Mac-PC/svn/Project/com/mycompany/TempT/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/TempT-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.212s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 13 20:34:55 ICT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/111M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ForSentProject: Could not resolve dependencies for project MyMaven.Project.app:ForSentProject:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.mycompany:TempT:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in Repo (https://Mac-PC/svn/Project) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

it said Could not find artifact.

My pom.xml is like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>MyMaven.Project.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>ForSentProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>ForSentProject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>TempT</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

     <repositories>
      <repository>
         <id>Repo</id>
         <url>https://Mac-PC/svn/Project</url>
      </repository>
   </repositories>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

and Setting.xml is like this:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

    <servers>
     <server>
          <id>Repo</id>
          <username>pee</username>
          <password>pee</password>
        </server>
        <server>
          <id>Repo-releases</id>
          <username>pee</username>
          <password>pee</password>
        </server>
      </servers>


</settings>
```

my pom.xml that I have deploy is like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>TempT</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>TempT</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <!--............... -->
    <!-- <scm> -->
    <!-- <url>http://www.svn.com</url> -->
    <!-- <connection>scm:svn:https://Mac-PC/svn/Project/MyMaven/Project</connection> -->
    <!-- <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://Mac-PC/svn/Project/MyMaven/Project</developerConnection> -->
    <!-- </scm> -->

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
          <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
            <id>Repo-releases</id>
            <name>Release Repository</name>
            <url>svn:https://Mac-PC/svn/Project/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <!--............... -->


<!--............... -->
 <mailingLists>
        <mailingList>
            <name>Mailing List</name>
            <subscribe>rockbasic_ton@hotmail.com</subscribe>
            <unsubscribe>rockbasic_ton@hotmail.com</unsubscribe>
            <post>rockbasic_ton@hotmail.com</post>
            <archive>https://Mac-PC/svn/Project/keepList</archive>
        </mailingList>
    </mailingLists>
<!--............... -->


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tu.cs.jdbcDriver</groupId>
            <artifactId>jazz</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tu.cs.jdbcDriver</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-be</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tu.cs.jdbcDriver</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-col</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tu.cs.jdbcDriver</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-di</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tu.cs.jdbcDriver</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-log</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tu.cs.jdbcDriver</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tu.cs.jdbcDriver</groupId>
            <artifactId>table</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tu.cs.jdbcDriver</groupId>
            <artifactId>calendar</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
       <!--............... -->
        <extensions>
         <!--.............. -->
           <extension>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.wagon-svn</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-svn</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
            </extension>
             <!--.............. -->
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-scm</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-6</version>
            </extension>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scm-manager-plexus</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </extension>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnexe</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
        <!--............... -->

        <!--............... -->
<!--        <extensions> -->
<!--            <extension> -->
<!--                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId> -->
<!--                <artifactId>wagon-scm</artifactId> -->
<!--                <version>1.0-beta-6</version> -->
<!--            </extension> -->
<!--            <extension> -->
<!--                <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId> -->
<!--                <artifactId>maven-scm-manager-plexus</artifactId> -->
<!--                <version>1.0</version> -->
<!--            </extension> -->
<!--            <extension> -->
<!--                <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId> -->
<!--                <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnexe</artifactId> -->
<!--                <version>1.0</version> -->
<!--            </extension> -->
<!--            <extension> -->
<!--                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId> -->
<!--                <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId> -->
<!--                <version>2.4</version> -->
<!--            </extension> -->
<!--        </extensions> -->
        <!--............... -->

        <plugins>
            <!--............... -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0-beta-9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
                    <goals>deploy</goals>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--............... -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\javac.exe
                    </executable>
                    <compilerVersion>1.7</compilerVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


        <!--............... -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.mycompany.TempT.Main</mainClass>
                            <packageName>com.mycompany.TempT</packageName>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        <!--............... -->
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <!--............... 
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Repo-releases</id>
            <name>Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://Mac-PC/svn/Project/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    ............... -->

</project>
```

Comment: Do you really want to use a Subversion repository (mostly for source code) as a Maven binary repository?

Comment: What does this have to do with Git?

Answer (score 0):

Maven does not resolve dependencies from **source** repositories such as SVN. You need an artifact repository (there are both free and paid software that can provide this, or you can install your dependency to the local filesystem).

If this is a non-public artifact, you should first [install it to your local repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html):

> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=path-to-file -DgroupId=group-id -DartifactId=artifact-id -Dversion=version -Dpackaging=packaging